# Adding Skip Navigation Links

Tags: html, css

I am working on adding skip navigation links and for the start/top of the site I used some code from another source and it is working fine. The code below shows the  skip to main link when the tab button is hit for the first time.

I also want to add a "Skip the Side navigation" button that will actually show up inside of the side menu div and not at the top left screen.
A few things that I have tried have shown the link when the page loads, instead of just tab. Obviously if I use the same code as the #skip code it shows in the left corner.

Looking for help on hiding the "skip side navigation" link until focus and display it at the top of the side menu div.

HTML

```
<div id="skip">
  <a href="#content">Skip to Main Content</a>
</div>

CSS
#skip a{display: block;position: absolute;left: -999px;top: -999px; color:7dc33a;}
#skip a:focus{left: 0;top: 0;padding: 3px; background: #ffffff; border:1px solid #f8f8f8;}



HTML for Side Menu
<div id="accordian">
<div id="skipside">
    <a href="#footer">Skip Side Navigation Links</a>
</div>
<ul>
<li class="active">
<h3>Header</h3>
<ul>
<li><a href="links</a>  </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: coud you please recreate what you are trying to acomplish on this website then post the ink in the comments here or edit your questions.

https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: All that I am trying to do is when a user comes to the site and only has keyboard access to tab through. I want to give them the option to skip to main content(which I already do). As they continue to tab through and hit the side menu, I want to give them the same option. A link that stays hidden until it receives focus, shows and disappears with the next tab press. You can see an example on this site just press tab when the page loads https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/5-website-accessibility-checkers    I just need this to appear within my side menu which is "accordian" in code

Comment: thanks for the website ink, got a working example, see my Answer... please accept if it solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

here you go bro. this is what you are looking for, thanks for providing the website link.

https://jsfiddle.net/ukreLc9y/

**HTML**

```
<div style="outline:none" tabindex="-1">
  <a href="#main-content" class="page__content-skip-link">Skip to main content</a>
  <div class="page" id="top">TEST</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.page__content-skip-link:active, .page__content-skip-link:focus {
    position: static!important;
    clip: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
.page__content-skip-link:active, .page__content-skip-link:focus {
    position: static!important;
    clip: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
.page__content-skip-link {
    position: absolute!important;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
    background-color: #012635;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
.page__content-skip-link {
    position: absolute!important;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
    background-color: #012635;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
```